# mips firmware in mips debian: chroot Illegal instruction

Tags: debian, mips, qemu, firmware, chroot

I want to run a firmware in a debian emulation environment.

When I enter chroot command, I get error Illegal instruction.

But I think the architecture is the same, as I will show you as the follow. And I can run the bin/busybox directly, but I can't chroot to the dir with it as the bash.

here is the details:

[image: the running details]

The virtual environment for the firmware I created is debian stretch(9.11.0) mipsel.

Will it be because of the sub-architecture? For example, my machine is malta but the firmware actually runs in loongson. Can a program run in loongson run in malta? (Actually I don't know the firmware's environment, what I have is only the ubifs/ files.)

Comment: In this setup, are you using QEMU's linux-user emulation in a chroot (ie the host is x86-64 and the binaries inside the chroot are mips), or are you using QEMU's system emulation to run a complete MIPS kernel, and then within that emulated system using a chroot to run the binaries from the loongson box?

Comment: I suspect that the illegal instruction was a loongson instruction, but your Malta machine has an older CPU, (a 24K?). Looking at the core dump with gdb should help.

Comment: @PeterMaydell I am using QEMU's system emulation to run a complete MIPS(malta) kernel, and within it using the chroot to run the firmware file system, but actually I don't know wether it comes from loongson box or not, the only message I get is from the file command that it is from MIPS architecture.

Comment: @markgz Sorry, I get what you mean until now. You mean my cpu model is older than the firmware's cpu model so there is some instructions I can't run, right? I am using qemu emulation to run the firmware, and the kernel I use is vmlinux-4.9.0-11-4kc-malta, it actually is MIPS 24Kc. So, where can I get a newer cpu model kernel? It seems that only have 24K? And another question, since the cpu model is older, why I can run it directly? Thank you very much.

Comment: @markgz Thanks for your help, I found I can choose the cpu when start the system with qemu-system-mipsel. After I choose a newer cpu(74Kc), it works.

Answer (score 1):

Thank for @markgz's reply, I have solved this problem.

It is because I have an old cpu model(24kc).

You can choose the cpu model when you start the debian system with qemu-system-mipsel. After you choose a newer cpu model such as 74Kc, it works in my situation. Maybe this can help you too.